# How can I put a response in a separate lambda behind websocket api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a AWS API Gateway with websocket connection. And there is a lambda (LA) which is called by this API gateway and it sends a request to another service along with the websocket connection ID. After that it exists. 
There is another lambda `LB` which is listening on some backend data store. The data store service will call `LB` if there is any update event. The event includes websocket conneciton ID. And I'd like to let `LB` send an update event to API gateway which forward this event to clients over websocket connection.
This is a communication mode in my mind. My question is whether API gateway supports such mode. If yes, how does `LB` send response event to API gateway and to clients?

The communication looks like below screenshot. The question is whether it works? how the response lambda send event to API gateway?

[image]

I have added the Integration response as below. There are `Integration Request` and `Integration Response`. But I can only set up one lambda for both of them. How can I make different lambda for request and response?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works.

> API Gateway WebSocket APIs are `bidirectional`. A client can send messages to a service, and services can `independently` send messages to clients.

There are two ways to send response from your `lambda` to `api gateway`;

1) An integration can send a response, which is returned to the client by a route response that you have defined. Here are the [details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-route-response.html)

2) You can use the `@connections API` to send a `POST` request. For more information, see Use @connections commands in your backend service. Here are the [details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html)

Your case looks like option 2. Invoking `api gateway` using `connection api` at your `lambda`.

Comment: I have added a route response but the `Integration Response` and `Route Response` is grey out. I can't click on them to edit it.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao These are clickable if you mean that part https://prnt.sc/slp43x - you need to deploy - could you share a screenshot. You are going with the first option right ?

Comment: It is clickable on the `integration request`. What I mean is `Integration response`. In my mode, there are two lambdas, one for request, the other is for response. I am looking for a way to configure the `integration response` from a different lambda.

Comment: I figured out why `Integration response` is not clickable. Because it needs to be non-proxy integration. After change it to non-proxy integration, I can't setup two lambdas for request and response.

Comment: why two lambda functions for request/response - the same lambda will return the response via callback to api gateway. @JoeyYiZhao

Comment: Look at the diagram on my post, there are three lambdas, one for authorization, one for request, one for response.  When there is an update on database, it triggers the lambda which response to client. That's why I think there are two lambdas for response/response

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao check here please https://github.com/aws-samples/simple-websockets-chat-app/blob/master/sendmessage/app.js - also the repository - there are three lambdas one for connect/disconnect/sendMessage - sendMessage handles both.

Comment: This is not what I need. In your example, the sendMessage will handle both request and response. But in my case, the request and response are handled by different lambdas. Imagine, you have a lambda to listen on dynamodb stream, it needs to response to API gateway. How do you define that?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao https://www.serverless.com/blog/api-gateway-websockets-support/ this is the source of your image right ? It is also written in this post; "On invoke, the business logic would check your datastore for the connections subscribed to that channel, and `callback to API Gateway with the connectionId and your payload`."

Comment: Yes that's right. This is the source image. But I don't know how to `callback to API Gateway`. That's why I asked this question about how to use a different lambda to response to API Gateway. In api gateway console, I can't configure a different lambda for response.

Comment: The callback code is also mentioned in the sample code via Promises to `ApiGatewayManagementApi`. As far as i know it is not possible to handle response in a separate one. It may work - if you trigger dynamodb from sendmessage lambda - another lambda listens dynamodb table - then it promises all. Maybe someone else may have another option. That's my fuel :)

Comment: by looking at the callback method, it works pretty much like request/response rather than 2 way communication. With websocket, it should support push message from server to client once they have connected. My question is asking about how I can push message from server to client.

Comment: I think I figured out how it works. I can create a lambda to call the API `AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi` to send message to client via websocket. This lambda is not needed to be put in API Gateway definition. The API Gateway console is misleading me.